# Using Java Copy data from one oracle Database table to another database table

Tags: java, database, copy

I want to copy a table from one oracle database to another using Java. (JDBC APIs)
the two databases are disconnected from each other (i.e. they do not have any DBlinks pointing to each other).

Can someone specify the most efficient way to do this.

These tables will be having anywhere between 30,000 to 50,000 rows with 10 columns

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? ETLs are perfect for this.

Answer (score 0):

open a connection to database 1
open another connection to database 2
read from database 1 into java structures
write into database 2 from java structures.

or use an available off the shelf utility.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but can you explain while copying or reading the data from/to java structures whats are the best options to be used for read large chunks of data.

Comment: @Mrinmoy I suppose you can't retrieve all the data to the memory. Use a cursor to reading the data from database 1 and insert on database 2. This is an example for PosgtreSQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751690/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-retrieve-sequential-data-from-database